# Searchable CheckListBox in webform asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a checklistbox getting list of element from database and its working fine, 
I want to make it searchable i.e User may type and search any Name from List and submit the form.

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkJudges" runat="server" Font-Bold="false" Font-Names="verdana" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="#444444"></asp:CheckBoxList>
```

how can I search Items without postback request.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JQuery to make it searchable

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/jscript">
                function Search() {

                    var t = document.getElementById("txtSearching").value;

                   $('#cphContentBody_chkJudges tbody tr').each(function () {

                       var str = $(this).text();
                       if (str.toUpperCase().indexOf(t.toUpperCase()) >= 0) {

                           $(this).show();
                       } else {
                           $(this).hide();
                       }
                   });

                }

            </script>
            <input  type="text" id='txtSearching' onInput="return Search();" />
```